# Problems with read permissions

Tags: permissions, office-integration

I have a user with **read** permission for library with excel files. When user clicks on document it opens in readonly mode, but user has option to edit file and if he does that all changes are saved on server.  I think it's strange - read permission should **not allow to modify** document, but it **dose**. Any idea how to solve this issue?

---

[**EDIT**] So lets sum up:  1) excel file is document library with unique permissions, only I and enother user can access it, all other groups and users excluded; 2) excel file inherits permissions from document library; 3) that user has read permission and all over the site he never gains write permissions directly or trough group; 4) When i with write rights open the file i get pop-up window it asks me I want to read file or edit it, if user opens it - he gets message that this file  can be harmfull; 5) Excel file is opened Excel 2010 and states that file is opened in readonly mode from server, but you can click *edit workbook* and save - saves are made on server; 6) I checked that user can modify any excel file in directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double-check that the user was not inadvertently included in some other group with write permissions. While the user may still be allowed to save it locally (unless you are using Information Rights Management server), he or she should not be allowed to save the doc back to a document library with just read permission.

Comment: This folder has unique permissions so i don't think that the issue

Comment: I don't suppose the user in question would be a site collection administrator by chance? That would override it...

Comment: Let me say again - its just a simple user, his not admin. Folder with documents has unique permissions and his permissions are set to **read**

Comment: I don't see where you said before that it was not an admin user. User can mean a lot of things. Forgive me if I missed it. Well, somewhere up or down the chain this user is being given write permissions. When you say "folder" do you actually mean a folder in a document library (my assumption), or is the document simply in a document library?  Also, does this occur for all documents in the folder or just the one?  I wonder if write permission was granted at the document level itself?  It would also override the folder permission.

Comment: Rob i have updeted my question

Comment: Ashvay-I was unable to recreate the problem exactly, but I may have something for you to try.

I tested on a library set up similar to yours.  Everything went exactly as you describe, except at the end.  The save dialog opened up and appeared as if it was going to let me save to the server, but I was prevented when I hit the OK button.  I got a dialog that said the file was read only.  I know that your situation is different because you said that you verified that the save actually occurred.

So I set the library up to require checkout (in the version settings). [Read on in next comment...]

Comment: So after requiring checkout, when I open the document I still was able to hit the button to enable editing, but it didn't actually allow me to edit.  In fact, I could not even type into the document.  So it looks like there may be problems there with Office 2010.  However, if you don't currently require checkout, maybe try that to see if it will resolve the issue for you.

Comment: After enabling check in/out user has no options to check in or out from ribbon, but when the file is downloaded it states that object is checked out and when I modify it asks me if I want to check in the changes and saves them. Also I created other library and did the routine and achived same result. Checked permissions for user - read. It seems that it's some sort of issue with Office.

Comment: I think the only way to deal with it is to remove user with read writes from document library and create workflow that will copy document to some library after it was checked where user can read it, without any changes to original file

Comment: Is it good idea?

Comment: You can do that with a workflow or with an event handler (using Visual Studio) if you have that capability.  I agree with you that it is a workable solution.  It is a shame that you should have to do it because of a bug in the product.  Good luck.

Comment: I accept this answer as solution beacuse it has many ideas how to make/check if file can be readonly + Rob (Big thanks) and I recomend to use workflow or event handler.